# hide div on click based on a sum value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 divs in total. I did another div with black colour on one of them. I implemented the button 'add another plan' and I want that it to hide the black div if the sum(Variable show in the JSFiddle) is not equal to 5.

**JS**:

```
$(function () {

    $(".plan-quantity").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

    $(".button").on("click", function () {

        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
        var sum = 0;
        $('.plan-quantity input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });

        if ($button.text() == "+" && sum < 5) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;

            if ($button.text() == "+" && sum > 0) {
                var discount = ((sum * 5) * 24) + 120;
                $(".total-discount").html('Total savings on all plans over 2 years: &euro;' + discount);
            }

        } else if ($button.text() == "-") {
            // Don't allow decrementing below zero
            if (oldValue > 0) {
                var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                var discount = (((sum * 5) * 24) - 120);
                $(".total-discount").html('Total savings on all plans over 2 years: &euro;' + discount);

                if (newVal == 1) {
                    $(".total-discount").html('Total savings on all plans over 2 years: &euro;0');
                }

            } else {
                newVal = 0;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });

});

function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('handset-m').checked) {
        document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;20';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;18';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('handset-l').checked) {
        document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;35';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;25';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('handset-xl').checked) {
        document.getElementById('price-xl').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;55';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('price-xl').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;35';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('handset-xxl').checked) {
        document.getElementById('price-xxl').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;75';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('price-xxl').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;50';
    }
}
```

This is the JS for the hiding part I am trying to use but not managing unfortunately:

```
$(".button-hide").click(function() {
         $("#disable").hide();
        });

        }else{
            alert("Not Possible to have more then 5");
            }
```

I have the fiddle here you can understand better: http://jsfiddle.net/C34AQ/1/

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you want to hide the black div on click of the `add another plan` button?

Comment: Yes exactly, but it should work in collaboration of the sum value. If the sum value is greater equal to 5 it will not allow you and alert you while if its less than 5 it will

Comment: ok but i don't see any "hiding" related code. does this mean that you haven't tried any code to hide the appropriate "element"?

Comment: I did not include it in the Fiddle neither in the question, I did try and I managed to succeed to hide but not working with the sum value. I will edit the question and put the code I used to hide in it.

Comment: ok great. are you getting any errors? check your javascript console

Comment: @anurupr I have edited my question - Have a look now and many thanks for your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49921/discussion-between-anurupr-and-user3025379)

Comment: and what is 'sum value' ?? would you mind making your question clear? sum of what? it could be anything.. number of divs, total values of text boxes etc..

Comment: @TilwinJoy, SUM is a variable in which can be clearly visible in the JS Fiddle

Comment: @you need to clarify what data that variable holds. you are using it in many places, its value could become 5 anywhere. at what point you want to hide the div, nothing is clear.

Comment: @TilwinJoy apologies for my unclear question. What I am trying to achieve is that the button 'Add another plan' should allow you to hide the div if the sum value not equal to 5. if it is then if you press the 'Add another plan' it alerts you that you cannot. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: @user3025379 would be nice if you accept the answer. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You haven't added query in your fiddle so nothing is working (`$ undefined`)
- `$(".button").on("click", function () {` you are using `.button` class to select the button but your button doesn't have such a class. it has `button-hie` class instead.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/C34AQ/4/)

```
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
    var sum = 0;
    $('.plan-quantity input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());

    });

    if(sum<5) $("#disable").hide();
    else alert('your alert');
```

Comment: The code above is working however now when the +/- buttons are not working when changed the type to button not text. It is not showing on the fiddle as the images are hosted locally for the time being

Comment: @user3025379 what do you mean you changed type to button not text? you don't have to change any text. just change `$(".button").on("click", function () {` to `$(".button-hide").on("click", function () {`
or as in the code above

Comment: @user3025379 just check my fiddle. what is not working in it?

Comment: in the fiddle, near the text box where u put the number in, there should be two buttons '+' and a '-' where you add the value dynamically, however when I pasted the code from your fiddle, the div worked but the plus and minus stopped working, reason behind is because `$("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {` was changed to `$("input[type='button']").on("click", function () {`

Comment: i didn't change any `$("input[type='text']")`. i just changed `$(".button").on("click", function () {` as i said above in the answer. read the ans properly. if you add value to the text boxes it's still working, which is why if you add something more than 5 it gives the alert.

Comment: @user3025379 and what makes me wonder is there is no such line - `$("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {` in your fiddle. then what do you mean by it's changes? how could i change something that is not there?

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. Don't worry about it. Your code is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score -2):

Take a hidden field on the form,and update its value everytime.Just before the hide function,check if the value of the hidden field is 5 or not.If it is 5 then hide it.

Comment: The value is already there if you check the fiddle, I want to combine the hide functionality with SUM variable already available in the code.

Comment: That what I am saying,You will have to use <input type="hidden">,and update its value everytime.